# Source code was not found for app:///index.android.bundle

Tags: react-native, source-maps, sentry

I've installed a hosted sentry on my server and integrated my react native application with it. Everything works well except linking the stack-trace with the sourcemap. The captured exception shows this error:

```
Source code was not found for app:///index.android.bundle
```

I have reviewed the document of sentry but I could not figure it out. I have also uploaded the ~/index.android.bundle and ~/index.android.bundle.map
to the sentry server and I can see them inside the Artifacts tab.

I expected the stack-trace of errors to be shown but I get

```
app:///index.delta in captureException at line 108830:23
app:///index.delta in onUnhandled at line 111447:33
app:///index.delta in onUnhandled at line 22937:30
[native code] onUnhandled
app:///index.delta at line 24072:26
app:///index.delta in _callTimer at line 23989:17
app:///index.delta in callTimers at line 24196:19
app:///index.delta in __callFunction at line 2483:49
app:///index.delta at line 2256:31
app:///index.delta in __guard at line 2437:15
app:///index.delta in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue at line 2255:21
[native code] callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

- Sentry SDK: sentry-react-native